# How to statistically test if two continuous variables can combined to be proxies of one categorical variable? MANOVA?

Tags: anova, manova

In the dataset I have, there's one categorical variable (A) containing multiple levels. Due to multiple reasons, I want to use continuous variables only for modeling. I feel two other continuous variables (B, C) combined should be good proxies of A. In other words, I want to prove B and C combined are significantly different among levels in A.

So far, I have used MANOVA and got pretty good results. However, I feel MANOVA is more designed for testing if A has an effect on B and C, and here I don't have any causality involved.  Is MANOVA the way to go?

Comment: Nothing about MANOVA is inherently causal.